# Order of Magnitude of BigDecimal

Tags: java, precision, bigdecimal

I am trying to measure the accuracy of a computed result (as a double), compared to a BigDecimal with the known correct result to arbitrary precision. I want to make sure it is correct up to x decimal places. I figure this can be done like so:

(order of magnitude of correct result) - (order of magnitude of difference) > x

I am having trouble finding a simple way to compute the order of magnitude of a BigDecimal though. Any ideas?

If this is a bad way to measure accuracy, I would be open to other techniques.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check the number of correct decimal places you just want the order of magnitude of the difference, not the order of magnitude of the correct result. So I suppose you need to convert your `double` computed result to a `BigDecimal`, subtract the precise result, then convert back to a `double` and take the logarithm in base 10.

Or if you just need to check whether the result is accurate to x decimal places then just check if the difference is greater than 0.5 * 10^(-x), or equivalently:

```
int x = 3; // number of decimal places required
BigDecimal difference = accurateResult.subtract(new BigDecimal(approxResult));
BigDecimal testStat = difference.movePointRight(x).abs();
boolean ok = testStat.compareTo(new BigDecimal(0.5)) <= 0;
```

Actually that probably isn't quit right depending on exactly what you mean by "correct to x decimal places" and how rigorous you need to be. You could say that 0.15001 and 0.24999 are equal to 1 decimal place (both round to 0.2) but that 0.19999 and 0.25001 are not even though the difference is smaller. If you go that way I think you just have to explicitly round both numbers to x decimal places and then compare.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be interested only in a rough estimate: you should compare the log_10 of both values, which tells you the order of magnitude of you error... You can get a good approximation of log_10 of a BigInteger by looking at the length of its decimal representation `toString(10).length()`